# How can I import a vector format file into Google Drawing

Tags: vector, svg, sketch-app, eps, google

Apparently this is not possible out of the box. I have found some crazy workarounds that require using different operating systems and 4 different applications but I was hoping for something simpler

The original app i'm using to author the vector files is Sketchapp.

Comment: Looks like they have removed this capability. I just tried all of the above methods (worked in the past for me) but now it is no longer working. Google Drawing has now become very limited.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm thinking about writing a command line tool for this.

**My workflow is constantly:**

- Upload to google drive
- Cloud convert to emf
- Then open in google draw

Comment: what's cloud convert?

Comment: This works great for vector but is there any way to keep the text editable

Answer (score 0):

The below has worked in the past, but there are multiple reports it no longer works as of mid-2019.

1. Upload your images/icons to Google Drive
2. Open it with CloudConvert

   - Choose export format : vector / emf.
   - Make sure that you have the checkbox to save the converted file to your Google Drive
     [image]
   - Click on button Start conversion.
3. Open emf file with Google Drawing
4. Copy/paste SVG icon into your Slides.

   - you can modify the colors as you wish, add or remove shapes

[image]

Comment: Alas, Google Drawings does not support importing .EMF files anymore :( That sucks!

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2023, some EMFs in Google Drive can no longer be opened without an additional step. In the past, CloudConverted EMFs could be opened with Google Drawings and copied into Slides, enabling vector graphic editing in Google Drive.

Now those CloudConverted EMFs need to be edited before Google Drive will open them in Google Drawings.

Change the CloudConverted EMF file MimeType from 'image/emf' to 'application/x-msmetafile' and it should be able to open.

Here is a Google App script to do this for you: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GuARFGTqiIBcMpAEI3K_SuT1UiLwMxjHOwVm88yNMeY/edit